# How to Integrate PayUMoney payment gateway with Angular2/4/5

Tags: angular5, payment-gateway, sha256, payumoney, payu

i am working with angular5 , i need to integrate PayUMoney payment gateway in my application , for that i added following form and test with "https://test.payu.in/_payment" domain.

Error :

> Error Reason Transaction failed due to incorrectly calculated hash
>   parameter.
>
> Corrective Action Please ensure that the hash used in transaction
>   request is calculated using the correct formula. Please note the
>   correct formula for calculating the value of hash:
>   sha512(key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5||||||SALT)
>
> Based on above formula and applying for this transaction, hash should
>   be calculated as mentioned below : hash =
>   sha512(gtKFFx|ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5da|500|merit application
>   fees|bhagvat lande|landebm@gmail.com|||||||||||eCwWELxi) = Array
>
> As seen above, correct hash value should have been - Array
>
> But the hash posted in the transaction request from your end was -
>   e95bd46ce3cf4b3c32a63ba5f51934ef8506e0e47027512f41bff125be02cd14

My Component with Form

```
<form #f method="post" id="payu-payment-form" action="https://test.payu.in/_payment">
        <input type="hidden" name="hash" value="e95bd46ce3cf4b3c32a63ba5f51934ef8506e0e47027512f41bff125be02cd14"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="key" value="gtKFFx" />
        <input type="hidden" name="txnid" value="ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5da" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="500" />
        <input type="hidden" name="productinfo" value="merit application fees" />
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="bhagvat lande" />
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="******@gmail.com" />
        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="+91**********" />
        <input type="hidden" name="surl" value="http://localhost:4200/#/payment/payment-success" />
        <input type="hidden" name="furl" value="http://localhost:4200/#/payment/payment-error" />
        <input type="hidden" name="service_provider" value="" />
        <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" (click)="f.submit()" value="submit" formtarget="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-money"></i>&nbsp;Proceed To Pay</button>
      </form>
```

in above form i just generate one dummy hash key(SHA-256) and put their.

**Questions :**

- how to integrate PayUmoney payment gateway in ANgular2/4/5 ?
- they provided formula on their documentation for generation hash key , it tooks all other forms fields and generate hash key (SHA-256) , is their any way to create hash key at client side and how to use that ?

thanks

Comment: No one is answering if we ask payumoney in angular6/7/8.

Comment: @NilaVaani yes, I posted this question when I am new to angular, but now I understand that this form needs to submit from the server-side itself, just on the client-side you need to send possible inputs to API if required. Thanks

Comment: How can i implement in my angular 8?

Comment: I have asked many question related this but no one is answered.so if you know please help me to find solution

Comment: @Nila You don't need to implement in angular you should write apis with any backend language such as node , PHP , java etc just call that api in angular app . It's very secure to put this code on backend .